# Understanding callback function purpose

Tags: javascript, callback

I realise this is more of a general question, but I've read through similar answers on here but I can't find more of an overview. I'm new to callbacks and I'm trying to understand when they should be used.

The MDN web docs has this example;

```
function greeting(name) {
  alert('Hello ' + name);
}

function processUserInput(callback) {
  var name = prompt('Please enter your name.');
  callback(name);
}

processUserInput(greeting);
```

However I'm struggling to see how this is more beneficial than the following, where I'm not passing the greeting function as a parameter?

```
function greeting(name) {
  alert('Hello ' + name);
}

function processUserInput() {
  var name = prompt('Please enter your name.');
  greeting(name);
}

processUserInput();
```

Comment: Easier to test, more loosely coupled, closer to single responsibility principle ideal.

Comment: Because you could also pass in a function that does something other than alert the name, such as console.log the name for example

Comment: What if you wanted to alert something else after you've got their name?

Comment: The point of that example is to be ultra-simple so you can see how it works. It is not supposed to be an example of how callbacks are useful.

Comment: @George, could this not be achieved after greeting(name) in my second example, as well as after callback(name) in the first? I've read a long article with some complex callbacks however I'm trying to get my head around when they should typically be used. I appreciate the responses, I'll read up on all of your points.

Comment: @paddyfields it depends, what if you've got `processUserInput` defined somewhere else to be used across different pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple terms you can say a callback is a way of asking a question (or requesting a task) in advance, i.e. when you're done with this do this (usually with the result). The whole point is to set aside functions that are to be done later, usually because you don't have the required inputs to do them now. 
The 2 main differences between your implementation and the MDN one is that yours is harder to maintain and harder to reason about hence test.

**1. Maintanance / Reusability**

Imagine you're a few thousand lines of code into a code base then you're required to change what processUserInput() does. Its much easier to change or write a new callback function instead of changing the function processUserInput(). This would be evident if processUserInput was a bit more complicated. This also means the MDN one is much more useful in various scenarios unlike your implementation. You can reuse it in different situations like saying good bye, capitalizing names etc simply by writing different callbacks to plug into processUserInput().

**2. Testing / Easier to reason about**

The MDN implementation is much more easier to understand. Its easier to assume that the function processUserInput(greeting) will probably return a greeting than it is to assume what processUserInput() does. This makes it easier to test because you can always be sure the MDN implementation will always return the same output given an input.

Answer (score 6):

As Javascript is async, sometimes it is difficult to handle response from non-blocking functions, for ex. if you are making an ajax call then it'll be executed asynchronously and results will be returned sometime later, by that time the main execution flow will pass the ajax code and starts executing following statements, in that case, its very difficult to catch the response to process further.

To handle those cases, callbacks comes into picture where you pass a function as the parameter to the ajax function and once the response is returned then call the callback by passing response data as a parameter to process further.

more info here http://callbackhell.com/

Answer (score 1):

Callbacks can be extremely useful depending on the circumstances; for example, when working with JavaScript for Google Chrome browser extension development, a callback can be used for intercepring web requests once it has been setup.

The purpose of a callback in general is to have the callback routine executed upon a trigger - the trigger being an event of some kind. Usually, functionality follows an interface of chained APIs. By implementing callback support, you can redirect execution flow during a stage of an operation. Callbacks are especially useful to third-party developers when dealing with someone elses library depending on what they are trying to do. Think of them like a notification system.

Functions in general taking in parameters is useful for flexibility and maintenance. If you use different functions for different things, the functions can be simply re-used over and over again to provide different functionality - whilst still preventing bloating the source code with more-or-less the same code over and over again. At the same time, if you use functions to your own library and a bug shows up, you can simply patch it for the one function and then it will be solved.

In your example, your passing a callback routine to the function you're calling - the function you're calling will call the callback function and pass the correct parameters. This is flexible because it allows you to have a callback routine called for printing the contents of the variable, and another for calculating the length of the string passed in, or another for logging it somewhere, etc. It allows you to re-use the function you setup, and have a different function called with the correct parameters without re-making the original function.

Answer (score -2):

This example is not appropriate for understanding callbacks

In simple Language callbacks functions are used when we have to do some stuff **after** or in response of some other event or function or expression.
i.e when the parent function completes its execution then callback gets executed.

simple Example

```
function hungerStatus(status,cb){
    return cb(status)
}
function whatToDo(status){
    return status ? "order Pizza" : "lets play"
}

hungerStatus(false,whatToDo)
```

Another example

```
// global variable​
​var allUserData = [];
​
​// generic logStuff function that prints to console​
​function logStuff (userData) {
    if ( typeof userData === "string")
    {
        console.log(userData);
    }
    else if ( typeof userData === "object")
    {
        for (var item in userData) {
            console.log(item + ": " + userData[item]);
        }
​
    }
​
}
​
​// A function that takes two parameters, the last one a callback function​
​function getInput (options, callback) {
    allUserData.push (options);
    callback (options);
​
}
​
​// When we call the getInput function, we pass logStuff as a parameter.​
​// So logStuff will be the function that will called back (or executed) inside the getInput function​
getInput ({name:"Rich", speciality:"JavaScript"}, logStuff);
```

refer [callback exaplanation](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/)