# How can i get value of default javascript geolocation function?

Tags: javascript, w3c-geolocation

I'd like to get the user_longitude and user_latitude values ​​outside of the function, but I don't really understand how to do that. Why? This is the first time I'm dealing with a function that is a bit strange for me, because I understand that the success function is an argument in *navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success)* but at the same time it has an additional *pos* argument, which is later used in crd, so my additional question is:

What is the *pos* argument?

```
function success(pos) {
            const crd = pos.coords;
          
            console.log('Your current position is:');
            console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
            console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
            console.log(`More or less ${crd.accuracy} meters.`);

            const user_latitude = crd.latitude

            const user_longitude = crd.longitude

            return user_longitude, user_latitude
          }

        
          
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success)
```

Comment: It's an object returned by `getCurrentPosition` when it's successful - you can write `console.log(pos)` in the success function to inspect it.

Comment: @Andy Okey, i am dumb. Thank you for the answer. So how can i get that object values outside that function?

Comment: You don’t. You get it inside the function, and that’s where you do with it whatever you have to do.

Comment: @fasfrtewqt2354r2edrq you need to put/move all logic that depends on `user_longitude` & `user_latitude` inside `success`  function (callback).

Comment: @bogdanoff And that's what i was asking for, cause i don't understand how to call that values and i am pretty sure i wrote it in my question. I asked for that logic, when i was saying "This is the first time I'm dealing with a function that is a bit strange for me, because I understand that the success function is an argument in navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success) but at the same time it has an additional pos argument, which is later used in crd".

Comment: @bogdanoff For now these functions 
success(pos) and navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success)
 look for me like function_1(argument_1) and function_2(function_1) and nothing more. I can't call just inside function cause i need to fetch it via POST request.

Comment: @fasfrtewqt2354r2edrq so you need to send location to server my making `fetch` request ?. then call `fetch(url, ....)....` inside `success` function.

Comment: you can also convert `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` into Promise if you know how to use Promise & you are confident about it.

Comment: Maybe start here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47907070/476